# lightdm automatically logs in

Tags: password, lightdm, ubuntu-mate

Lightdm logs me in, automatically, on boot, but I want it to ask for the password.

In the users and groups section of the control panel, it says my password will be asked for on boot, but this does not happen. Is there a reset, or some way i can make lightdm ask for my password?

This is on Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

If there is a `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, it is actually not needed in Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  I just tested this in a VM, and I removed the file altogether `sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, and rebooted.  Now it shows me the greeter with the login.

---

There is probably an autologin setting in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file.  I had the same issue till I commented out the line so now it looks like this:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:/etc/lightdm$ cat lightdm.conf
[Seat:*]
#autologin-user=terrance
```

This line can be commented out with one command:

```
sudo bash -c 'sed -i "s/autologin/#autologin/" /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'
```

When you reboot, it should now ask for user and password.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, but it forced me into booting to the terminal. I still want the greeter, but not the auto login. I tried setting autologin-user=false but the effect was the same

Comment: @j0h Edited.  Maybe try removing that file altogether.  It should have only two lines in it anyway.